# What is the number of the combination of the "three of a kind" in poker hands?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

So correct answer is$$ {13\choose1} {4\choose3}{12\choose2}{4 \choose1}{4 \choose1}
$$which has pretty simple explanation
choose 1 card of a value and choose 3 suits. choose 2 cards  of different value from rest and suit can be anything so choose any one suit

Now I am just thinking why we can't do it like this
choose 3 cards of different values. and then choose 3 suits for first card and then choose one - one suit for another 2 card value.
so, $$
{13\choose3}{4\choose3}{4\choose1} {4\choose1}$$

Answer (score 2):

You're forgetting about the choice of which of the three values you pick is actually the card that has three copies in the hand. Once we multiply your method by $\binom{3}{1}$, we do get the same answer - $54912$ in both cases.

Comment: hmm, then why don't we multiply for other value cards
(3choose1) for 3 copies card, (2choose1) for other 1 copy card and (1choose1) for last one

Comment: Because picking the value which shows up three times completely determines the hand - once you do that, you know that the other two values both show up on exactly one card and you don't need to do anything else with them.